# Accidentally forkbombing myself with start?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

this is my first question so if I've posted it in the wrong place, I'm sorry
For an assignment in college(Operating Systems 1), I have to make a simple batch dos menu. for commands with a lot of info, i have to run in a separate command shell with output piped through a pager (the “more” command), and with an appropriate title on the second command window, using the start command and a seperate batch file. I thought I figured it out, but every time I try to use one of the options where I'm piping it through more, I end up forkbombing myself (eg, it opens up a bajillion cmd and more.com processes. I have no idea why its doing this, how can I fix it?

The main menu script:
http://pastebin.com/kNwNZ8ex

dns.bat (all the other .bats are pretty much copies of this one)
http://pastebin.com/FRSQB944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `ipconfig.bat` file that is executing `ipconfig`, resulting in a call to itself.

Rename the batch file (recomended) or at least call `ipconfig.exe` from inside the batch file.